# BIM 360 Rename Folder API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

In BIM 360 folders have a 'name' and a 'display name'. The [folder patch endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-PATCH/) only supports changing the 'name'. It should also provide a means to change 'display name' because that is what applications will use. We discovered this when testing the rename functionality in our application. When getting the folder the 'name' was being returned with the new value, but the 'display name' was the original value.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue. Please bear with me checking with engineer team.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late reply. Our engineer team told me the API help doc incorrectly puts the description for **displayName** limitation in the response. PATCH folder should use name instead. I have asked engineer team to fix the document to put the desc to Request. Apology for the issue.

[image]